# Android: Read MP3/M4A Metadata Tags

Tags: android, metadata, mp3, m4a

I'm looking for a library that'll parse both mp3 and m4a metadata tags (basically I'd like to grab artist, song and duration information). I've scoured SO for answers and have only found solutions that work for mp3s or m4as, but not both (or solutions that're 2 or more years old that no longer work). I've read about reading the last 128 bytes of the file to parse the tags myself, but surely there has to be an easier way. I've tried several libraries including jaudiotagger, jid3lib, MyID3, Android's very own MediaMetadataRetriever, and the list goes on. MediaMetadataRetriever seems to have trouble reading mp3 files, however Play Music app doesn't seem to have any issues parsing the same mp3 files. Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Android's MediaStore implementation, found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

It was the cleanest and easiest to work with. In addition, I was testing on a Samsung device which I later found out that Samsung devices are notorious for parsing issues with mp3 metadata.

Answer (score 0):

jaudiotagger does work for both, so what problem did yo actually have when you attempted to use jaudiotagger.

Comment: Each file I tested with was different, but essentially fields like artist and title were null when they were populated.